# How to run two flask servers on different ports at the same time using bash script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, flask

I have two python files.

`server1.py`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello world from server 1."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=3000)
```

`server2.py`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello from server 2."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=4000)
```

Now, I need to run these two servers at the same time using a bash script.

I have tried this in my bash script.

`python3 server1.py && python3 server2.py`

When I run this bash script, it runs the `server1.py` file only when I quit **server 1** it runs the `server2.py`

Output of my bash script:

```
* Serving Flask app 'server1' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
^C * Serving Flask app 'server2' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:4000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I think its not possible to run two flask servers same time in a single terminal.
Is there any way using **bash** we can open a new terminal and run the `server2.py` file on that terminal? for some reasons, I need to run both flask servers same time.

Comment: `&&` is the wrong connector here; you want `&`. `&&` is for when you want to run the second command *only if* the first succeeds. `&`, on the other hand, runs the command before it in the background.

Comment: @Gordon Here I get a new problem, when I try to quit the servers by `ctrl + c` it only quits the second server. When I run the bash script again it says `Port 3000 is in use by another program. Either identify and stop that program, or start the server with a different port.` Here PORT 3000 is used by server 1.

Comment: `&` pushes the first `flask run` to the *background*, you will have to either manually bring it to the foreground using something like `fg %n` (%n inferred from `jobs` command corresponding to your process) and then use `CTRL+C` or use the `kill` command with the `PID` (process id) using something on the lines of `kill -9 <PID>`

Comment: @bguess yes it solved the problem.

Comment: Can you then validate the answer for the future users please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `&&` tells Bash to wait for the first command to ***successfully exit*** before running the second one.
A better solution might be `first_command & second_command &`.
This will send both scripts to run in the background at the same time and free up your TTY.
I wrote a post about Linux command chaining a few years ago, you might find it beneficial given your requirement.
You can read it [here](https://orelfichman.com/blog/chaining-linux-commands-like-a-pro)

Answer (score 1):

hope you are doing well,

Thank you for providing the scripts and servers configuration. With these I was able to reproduce what you got.

So

I think there is multiple solutions but I will give you two of them:

- The first is to deploy your servers into docker containers and run them either with a bash script or with docker-compose or in other container platforms.
- the second is, instead of using "&&" at the end of the command "python3 server1.py" that means "execute what comes after **this** only if what is before is executed and successful, you can just use "&" that means "execute what is **before** in the *background* and execute what is next in the same time. here is the bash script:

script.sh:

```
#/bin/bash
python3 server1.py &
python3 server2.py
```

it worked well for me but the problem with this is that even when you "ctrl-c" on your bash script output, the server2 will stop but not the server1:

```
❯ ps -aux
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
...
bguess     21149  0.0  0.2 178708 26480 pts/3    S    00:48   0:00 python3 server1.py
...
```

you will have to kill it manually with kill "PID_HERE" (kill 21149 in my example.)

Instead here is the solution with docker:
First lets modify your servers to listen on all host on port 4000 (since server1 and server2 will be isolated in 2 differents containers there will be no conflicts)

server1.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello world from server 1."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=4000, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

server2.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello from server 2."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=4000, debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Next, lets write down the two dockerfiles needed to build your containers images:

but first here is the requirements.txt file we will copy into our docker images:

requirements.txt:

```
flask
```

dockerfile1:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY server1.py .

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "server1", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0:4000"]

EXPOSE 4000
```

dockerfile2:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY server1.py .

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "server1", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0:4000"]

EXPOSE 4000
```

Now lets build the docker images from this 2 dockerfiles:

```
docker build -t so-flask-s1 -f dockerfile1 .
docker build -t so-flask-s2 -f dockerfile2 .
```

Now lets run our containers:

```
❯ docker run --rm -d -p 8081:4000 --name server1 so-flask-s1
7cfb16a63cd6de6ff2ecb9d728302a9f9ef0a848ab81a5cedf6ce9f60eaa66ae


❯ docker run --rm -d -p 8082:4000 --name server2 so-flask-s2
209013ba82f8c701ba46fd67675b9151056921a5a8b5a916e7f29b9014e7c9a1
```

Lets check if they are both running:

```
❯ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS             PORTS
            NAMES
209013ba82f8   so-flask-s2                          "python3 -m server2 …"   3 seconds ago    Up 2 seconds       0.0.0.0:8082->4000/tcp      server2
7cfb16a63cd6   so-flask-s1                          "python3 -m server1 …"   10 seconds ago   Up 9 seconds       0.0.0.0:8081->4000/tcp      server1
```

Now, lets check our browser:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this has helped you.

delete the images with:
docker rmi  #exemple:  docker rmi so-flask-s2

kill the containers with:
docker kill  #example: docker kill server2

here is a little cheat sheet (but you can find plenty of them on the internet): https://www.docker.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/docker-cheat-sheet.pdf

bguess

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @gordon-davisson, about the connector. But, if you are looking for a `bash` script to run your server, with different **port** configuration, it's better to use the `flask run` command line utility provided with the flask package.

Also, you don't need to change the **port** manually in the script, in case you again want to change the port, or the `configuration` i.e `debug=True/False` or the `hostname=0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1`

Some basics of it are (from it's help description):

```
flask run --help
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

  Run a local development server.

  This server is for development purposes only. It does not provide the
  stability, security, or performance of production WSGI servers.

  The reloader and debugger are enabled by default if FLASK_ENV=development
  or FLASK_DEBUG=1.

Options:
  -h, --host TEXT                 The interface to bind to.
  -p, --port INTEGER              The port to bind to.
  --cert PATH                     Specify a certificate file to use HTTPS.
  --key FILE                      The key file to use when specifying a
                                  certificate.
  --reload / --no-reload          Enable or disable the reloader. By default
                                  the reloader is active if debug is enabled.
  --debugger / --no-debugger      Enable or disable the debugger. By default
                                  the debugger is active if debug is enabled.
  --eager-loading / --lazy-loader
                                  Enable or disable eager loading. By default
                                  eager loading is enabled if the reloader is
                                  disabled.
  --with-threads / --without-threads
                                  Enable or disable multithreading.
  --extra-files PATH              Extra files that trigger a reload on change.
                                  Multiple paths are separated by ':'.
  --help                          Show this message and exit.
```

You can find great info on this topic at [flask run command](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-run-flask-application)